# Tool for Internet Explorer to view which css and javascript files loaded

Tags: internet-explorer

I feel ridiculous asking this, but for the life of me, I cannot recall what tool I used to use in Internet Explorer to view which js and css files have been loaded. (I'm using a CMS that uses tons of plugins and therefore tons of stylesheets - and of course, IE doesn't like that, so I need to know which files are taking preference in IE's 32 stylesheet limit). I recall that the tool would load up in a vertical frame in IE, showing the list of files. Does this sound familiar to anyone? Any suggestions for a similar type of tool would be appreciated.

Thanks guys!

Comment: F12 -->  That will open the consol you want

Comment: I know of the F12 "firebug-like" console. :) Thanks. Is it a particular menu option on there that will open up another window that shows a list of files? I'm pretty sure (but not completely certain), that it was an add-on for IE that I had installed.

Comment: I found a similar tool - http://www.ieinspector.com/dominspector/download.html (screenshot: http://www.ieinspector.com/dominspector/images/webpage_inspector_l.gif) - but it's not as nice as the one I used to use because that one worked side-by-side with the F12 console...this one doesn't. It's the file explorer window I'm really seeking.